# What do the curly braces around a process in pstree mean?

Tags: unix, pstree

The man page does explain what the bracket-braces means (it refers to threads), but I'm wondering what **just** the braces means.

From this here I can see that `auditd` and `node` are like this.

```
❯ pstree
init─┬─agetty
     ├─atd
     ├─auditd───{auditd}
     ├─crond
     ├─dbus-daemon
     ├─dhclient
     ├─6*[mingetty]
     ├─ntpd
     ├─rsyslogd───3*[{rsyslogd}]
     ├─2*[sendmail]
     ├─sshd─┬─sshd───sshd───zsh───tmux
     │      └─sshd───sshd───zsh───man───sh───sh───less
     ├─tmux─┬─2*[zsh]
     │      ├─zsh───node───{node}
     │      └─zsh───pstree
     └─udevd───2*[udevd]
```

My current best guess is that it means they are blocked on input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

n*[{name}] means group of the n threads. If there is only one thread, pstree use {name}

```
{auditd} <=> 1*[{auditd}]
```

**For group of threads, pstree use n*[{name}]:**

```
├─rsyslogd───3*[{rsyslogd}]
```

equipvalent to:

```
├─rsyslogd─┬─{rsyslogd}
           ├─{rsyslogd}
           └─{rsyslogd}
```

use command "pstree -a" to see the different.

Comment: `-c` is the correct argument to disable "compaction" of trees. `-a` does this implicitly as well (though it does not seem to work for me), but its main intention is to display arguments of processes. Source: [pstree(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?pstree+1)